# Scala: oneSet.diff(otherSet) not working

Tags: scala

I have a function that finds new columns to add to a cassandra table:

```
    val inputSet:Set[String] = inputColumns.map
    {
      cht => cht.stringLabel.toLowerCase()
    }.distinct.toSet
     logger.debug("\n\ninputSet\n"+inputSet.mkString(", "))

    val extantSet:Set[String] = extantColumns.map
    {
      e => e._1.toLowerCase()
    }.toSet

    logger.debug("\n\nextantSet\n"+inputSet.mkString(" * "))
    inputSet.diff(extantSet)
```

I want the values that are ONLY in the input set. I will then create columns in Cassandra table.

The return set (i.e., `inputSet.diff(extantSet)`),however, includes columns that are in both sets.

From my log files:

> inputSet
>
> incident, funnel, v_re-evaluate, adj_in-person, accident, v_create,....

---

> extantSet
>
> incident * funnel * v_re-evaluate * adj_in-person * accident *
>   v_create.....

---

> returned set:
>
> funnel | v_re-evaluate | adj_in-person | v_explain | v_devise | dmepos
>   |....

Which in the end throws

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid column name adj_in-person because it conflicts with an existing column
```

*What have I done wrong?*
Any help would be deeply appreciated?

Comment: Why you are doing distinct and to set both? And as you said you want the value which are only in input set then why you are taking difference of inputSet and externalSet?

Comment: natural language data....the toLowerCase can lead to duplicates. These still existed in the input set unless I used distinct.

Comment: also, extant means existing. I am looking for the difference between existing column names and input column names

Comment: and thanks for responding....any insights most welcome!

Comment: .toSet removes the duplicates so i think you don't need to do the distinct.

Comment: @Raman, that's what I thought too, but it didn't. My logging showed that duplicates created by using toLowerCase were in the Set.

Comment: According to the posted code, you are logging the `inputSet` twice and not logging the `extantSet` at all.

Comment: @jwvh...doh! thanls a million, really embarrassing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what i have tired. which gives me the output as follows.

```
object ABC extends App {

      val x = List("A","B","c","d","e","a","b").map(_.toLowerCase)
      val y = List("a","b","C").map(_.toLowerCase)
      println(s"${x diff y} List diff")
      println(s"${x.toSet diff y.toSet} Set diff")
    }
```

Output:

```
List(d, e, a, b) List diff
Set(e, d) Set diff
```

and i think you are looking for the set difference.

As you can see when we are taking the diff of two list then we are getting duplicates in the answer which are `a, b` but after the operation .toSet we are getting rid of duplicates so this should work for you too.

Comment: yes, this is correct. having fixed a very dumb error in my logging, I realized that the error was elsewhere and not in the diff function at all.